# "Tuviera" vs. "tuviese"

Tags: subjuntivo

Me gustaría preguntaros si para el oído del hablante nativo hay alguna diferencia semántica entre estas dos formas gramaticales:

> (a) Si yo **tuviera** un hijo, no le bautizaría.
>
> (b) Si yo **tuviese** un hijo, no le bautizaría.

Comment: Lo pregunto porque la explicación que me ha dado una compañera de estudios me parece rara... me dijo que si lo dijera mi abuela, diría „Si yo tuviese ...“ ya que se trata de una acción irreal porque esto ya no puede realizarse. Pero si lo dijera yo, debería usar la forma „tuviera“ ya que en este caso la acción se convierte en una acción hipotética porque sí puede suceder... :S

Comment: Aurora, ojalá y puedas visitar a la abuela y conversar con ella acerca de muchas cosas irreales e hipotéticas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutamente ninguna, al menos en lo que a la norma respecta. Según la zona y según preferencias personales, unas personas tienden más a usar la primera forma y otras la segunda, y por tanto es posible que les suene ligeramente más raro el uso de la que no acostumbran; pero según la RAE son equivalentes.

Comment: Según mi entender, en los sitios donde *-ra* plenamente prevalece, *-se* puede sonar algo más formal, pero no es tan grande la diferencia que sonaría fuera de lugar o llamativo (pero siendo alguien que prefiere *-se*, no puedo decírtelo por sensación personal)

Comment: yo lo prefiero más para ayudarme a entre los tres idiomas ibéricos que hablo. El portugués mantiene una distinción estricta (solo usa *-sse*) y entonces en castellano la mantengo (si no, a veces en portugués me saldría a veces un *-ra* erróneo). En asturiano, *-s(e)* ya no existe, entonces prefiero *-re* (en vez de *-ra*, también aceptable) para no confundirme — se usa tanto para el subjuntivo como el pluscuamperfecto como en el castellano y portugués literario. Me pregunto cómo es para los catalohablantes. @fedorqui ?

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente hay diferencias regionales al respecto, tal vez otras respuestas aclaren eso.

En mi caso, los chilenos preferimos cien por ciento la terminación -era. No hay en realidad ningún problema grave con decir "tuviese", pero suena raro, tal vez un poco formal, aunque más bien afectado o rebuscado tratandose del habla de compatriotas. Lo más probable es que al escuchar la terminación -ese entendamos que la otra persona es extranjera.

En algunos pocos casos la terminación -ese suena francamente mal. No estoy seguro de que esto sea así en todos los países, pero esta frase me suena mal:

> Si yo te quisiese ya te lo habría dicho.

<del>o peor</del>

> <del>Señorita, quisiese mostrarme ese reloj por favor.</del>

(Esto último es incorrecto, como me ha aclarado gentilmente guifa en los comentarios).

Comment: La segunda es incorrecta :-) por eso te suena tan mal

Comment: Uff. Pero "quisiera mostrarme..." ¿está bien?

Comment: Sí. En estas expresiones de cortesía, se está sustituyendo por «querría» (y tal sustitución no admite las formas con *-se*)

Comment: En México es parecido, según mi experiencia.  "Tuviese" suena un poco formal o afectado, como si la persona tratara de hablar con un estilo literario. // Creo que (en México) "tuviese" no se relaciona con ser de origen extranjero, porque la mayoría de los extranjeros que llegan a México no aspiran a usar el subjuntivo....